# Magento 2 TnC checkbox value not getting passed in custom payment method which redirects

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have created a custom payment gateway extension for CC and redirect both, the code for which can be found [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/splitit-paymentmethod.html).

Enabled TnC checkbox from the backend but unable to pass it's value to the `set-payment-information` from the custom payment method which I created to redirect the user to the payment gateway.

> Please review the code and let me know what needs to be done to improve
>   the extension.